# AngularJS - Passing date value from php to HTML5 date field?

Tags: php, angularjs, html

I am using AngularJS and currently I pass data from my PHP Controller to Angular with a json_encode like this:

echo(json_encode($result, true));

I also have a date inside of $result, that I want to use in a HTML5 date field. So in my results I have an Object like this:

```
"mhd":{"date":"2017-10-01 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"}
```

In my template I do:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in inventoryList | orderBy: 'mhd' | filter: invSearch track by item.id">
<td><input type="date" ng-model="item.mhd" /></td>
```

But this does not work, the date is not shown in the field. I also tried it with the following before passing the date back to angular, but here I get an error.

```
$entry['mhd'] = $entry['mhd']->getTimeStamp() * 1000;
```

Does anybody know how I need to return my result in php before json_encode to use it properly in my date field?

Thanks!

Comment: try using a filter like :  {{ item.mhd | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}

Comment: I think you are not catching object property , it should be like 
item.mhd.date

Comment: Both sugestions are not working :/ I always get this error message: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2017-12-01%2000:00:00.000000

And it looks like, that I need to parse the results in JavaScript first and create a date object there, but I am not sure if that's the real solution ...